# Css overflow hides all content. Can't modify scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my code i want something very simple. The white div's should always stay in horizontal center with fixed 80vw width and relative height. The vertical scrollbar should be hidden and the vertical should be auto. There is a problem because the horizontal scrollbar shows unnecessarily. When i try to hide it the whole content disappear and i can't figure out the problem.

```js
var array = ['cat', 'dog', 'lion', 'tiger', 'snake']
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (array.length));
    var n = array[random];
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.innerHTML += '<div class="box">' + n + '</div>';
}
```

```css
*{
outline:none;
transition:1s;

}
::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    display: none; 
}
html,body {
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100vw;

}

#container {

  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
    height:auto;
  width:100vw;
    background-color: black;
 
}

.box {
  height: auto;
  width:80vw;
  margin-left:10vw;
  margin-top:10vh;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:calc(2vh + 2vw);
    background-color: white;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set body and #container width to 100% should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use `overflow` to allow or not the scroll. 
[Here is a link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) to see how to use it.